# HTML form is not responsive

Tags: html, forms, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have the following code for my form. I am trying to make it responsive but it is not possible. When I add this code I have to scroll horizontally which I do not want. I want the whole table to fit in to my desktop without scrolling! any help?

```
<form id="calculateform_id" name="calculateform_name" method="post" onsubmit="return false;">
<div>
    <div class="bs-example">
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
            <tr class="info">
                <th></th>
                <th><h4>Member A</h4></th>
                <th><h4>Member B</h4></th>
                <th><h4>Member C</h4></th>
                <th><h4>Member D</h4></th>
            </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
            <tr class="active">
                <th>Name</th>
                <td>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="name" name="member1_name">
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td><div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></span>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="name" name="member2_name">
                </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="name" name="member3_name">
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="name" name="member4_name">
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="active">
                <th>Opportunity Cost / Salary</th>
                <td>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                        <input type="text" id="member1_ocs_id" class="form-control" onkeypress="return inputNumber(event);" name="member1_ocs" value="100,000" required="required">
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                        <input type="text" id="member2_ocs_id" class="form-control" onkeypress="return inputNumber(event);" name="member2_ocs" value="100,000" required="required">
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                        <input type="text" id="member3_ocs_id" class="form-control" onkeypress="return inputNumber(event);" name="member3_ocs" value="100,000" required="required">
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                        <input type="text" id="member4_ocs_id" class="form-control" onkeypress="return inputNumber(event);" name="member4_ocs" value="100,000" required="required">
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="active">
                <th>Hours Worked</th>
                <td>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon">#</span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="member1_hw_id" name="member1_hw" onkeypress="return inputNumber(event);" value="30" required="required">
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon">#</span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="member2_hw_id" name="member2_hw" onkeypress="return inputNumber(event);" value="40" required="required">
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon">#</span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="member3_hw_id" name="member3_hw" onkeypress="return inputNumber(event);" value="50" required="required">
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon">#</span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="member4_hw_id" name="member4_hw" onkeypress="return inputNumber(event);" value="60" required="required">
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="active">
                <th>Invested Cash</th>
                <td>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="member1_ic_id" name="member1_ic" value="0" onkeypress="return inputNumber(event);" >
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="member2_ic_id" name="member2_ic" value="0" onkeypress="return inputNumber(event);" >
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="member3_ic_id" name="member3_ic" value="0" onkeypress="return inputNumber(event);" >
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="member4_ic_id" name="member4_ic" value="0" onkeypress="return inputNumber(event);" >
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="active">
                <th>Contributed Cash</th>
                <td>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="member1_cc_id" name="member1_cc" value="500" required="required" onkeypress="return inputNumber(event);">
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="member2_cc_id" name="member2_cc" value="600" required="required" onkeypress="return inputNumber(event);">
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="member3_cc_id" name="member3_cc" value="750" required="required" onkeypress="return inputNumber(event);">
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="member4_cc_id" name="member4_cc" value="1,000" required="required" onkeypress="return inputNumber(event);">
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="active">
                <th>Date Joined The Project</th>
                <td>
                    <div class="input-group date" id='member1_datetimepicker'>
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" min="0" name="member1_djtp" placeholder="yyyy/mm/dd">
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="input-group date" id='member2_datetimepicker'>
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" min="0" name="member2_djtp" placeholder="yyyy/mm/dd">
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="input-group date" id='member3_datetimepicker'>
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" min="0" name="member3_djtp" placeholder="yyyy/mm/dd">
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="input-group date" id='member4_datetimepicker'>
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" min="0" name="member4_djtp" placeholder="yyyy/mm/dd">
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="success">
                <th>Your Share ($)</th>
                <td><input type="text" class="blue-color form-control" name="member1_ysc" disabled/></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="red-color form-control" name="member2_ysc" disabled/></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="orange-color form-control" name="member3_ysc" disabled/></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="green-color form-control" name="member4_ysc" disabled/></td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="success">
                <th>Your Share (%)</th>
                <td><input type="text" class="blue-color form-control" name="member1_ysp" disabled/></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="red-color form-control" name="member2_ysp" disabled/></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="orange-color form-control" name="member3_ysp" disabled/></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="green-color form-control" name="member4_ysp" disabled/></td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="success">
                <th>Total Share (#)</th>
                <td colspan="4"><b><input type="text" id="totalshare_id" class="form-control centered" name="totalshare" disabled/></b></td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML structure is not adequated to bootstrap (no .container / container-fluid element(s), no .row element(s), no col-* elements). Furthermore, you want a 5 columns table-like form to be responsive and i don't think it's a good idea for mobile devices.

I suggest you to muck-up a mobile view and a tablet devices like view (you already have desktop view), then proceed to use bootstrap to style each view.